# Issue with saving attachment to a new list item

Tags: sharepoint-server, development, custom-form, splistitem

I'm having an issue with adding attachements to a newly created SPList Item, the list item is created via a custom submission form built with ASP.NET and C#, I'm using the asp:fileupload control as follows:

```
<asp:FileUpload ID="AttachOne" runat="server" />
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvAttachOne" ControlToValidate="AttachOne" runat="server" ErrorMessage="*"/>
```

in the code behind I'm saving the attachment like this:

```
listItem.Attachments.Add(AttachOne.FileName, AttachOne.FileBytes);
...
listItem.Update();
```

The above code is working fine, but once the component got deployed to another environment, alot of items were submitted through the form without the attachments, **even though the file upload control is required** , also there were alot of items that are updated on the list along with their attachments.

For example if I have a list with more than 3000 items, there are like 400 items in the list that do not have attachments, and the rest 2600 items do have attachments.

Is there something I could look for to resolve this issue?
Is there something wrong with the ASP file upload control that made it drop files on form submission?

**Note:** I'm restricting the file types that could be uploaded through a regular expression formula.

```
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="revAttachOne" ControlToValidate="AttachOne" runat="server" ErrorMessage="message" ValidationExpression="^.*\.(pdf|PDF|jpg|JPG|png|PNG)$" SetFocusOnError="true"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```

Any help is much appreciated!